# Get starts and ends of following values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, grouping

I have an array of *following* (aka ordrered) values, and an array of picked values:

```
$orderedValues = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

$pickedValues = array("Jan", "Mar", "Apr", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Dec");
```

What I want is to have a resulting array giving me **each** *start* and *end* of the *following picked values*.

- The `$pickedValues` is already sorted the same way `$orderedValues` is.
- If a value is "alone", the value is the start and the next value is the end ; if the alone value is the last, then it is the end too.

In given example, the result should be as follow:

```
$result = array(
    array( // Alone value, end is the next from the order
        "start" => "Jan",
        "end" => "Feb"
    ),
    array(
        "start" => "Mar",
        "end" => "Apr"
    ),
    array(
        "start" => "Jul",
        "end" => "Sep",
    ),
    array( // Alone and last
        "start" => "Dec",
        "end" => "Dec"
    )
);
```

I have no clue how to achieve this kind of grouping. Any hints?

Comment: Pseudocode would be to iterate the picked values, search for the current one in the ordered values and then compare the next value in both. If different, you have your end. If not, keep going until you find a different one or reach the end.

Comment: Or you could try to rearrange picked values into groups of consecutive values first. After that it'd be rather easy finding out the end (if multiple elements, end is the last one, if single, find the next value from ordered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @El_Vanja's pseudo-code, here is what I came up to:

```
$orderedValues = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
$pickedValues = array("Jan", "Mar", "Apr", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Dec");

$result = array();
$index = null;
foreach ( $pickedValues as $k => $v ) {
    if ( $index === null ) {
        $index = array_search($v, $orderedValues);
    }

    $orderIndex = array_search($v, $orderedValues);
    if ( $orderIndex + 1 == count($orderedValues) ) {
        // last value
        $result[] = array(
            "start" => $orderedValues[$index],
            "end" => $orderedValues[$orderIndex],
        );
    } else {
        $nextOrderValue = $orderedValues[$orderIndex + 1];
        $nextValue = $pickedValues[$k + 1];
        if ( $nextOrderValue != $nextValue ) {
            $result[] = array(
                "start" => $orderedValues[$index],
                "end" => $orderedValues[$orderIndex],
            );
            $index = null;
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';
```

It looks like it's working, according to this [live sample](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/245168da54b79d444eab31a9d502a70820cf5281). Thanks!

Comment: Though this is a bit different than what you specified. In your answer middle elements end in `May` and `Oct`, but in the question they end in `Apr` and `Sep`. Either this isn't exactly what you're looking for or the question should be edited.

Comment: After the edit the live sample is completely off. Each entry from the picked values is just duplicated as the end.

Comment: Typo in the live sample, it's fixed now ;) thanks again